# Unable to get values for property from t:saveState whenever managed bean is in request scope

Tags: jsf-2, tomahawk

I am working in JSF, But i am not able to get the property values from t:saveState whenever managed bean is in request scope.

Here is my managed bean class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="demoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DemoBean {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String submitButton() {
        System.out.println("submitButton method");
        return "nextPage";
    }
}
```

index.xhtml page is here

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

<head>

</head>
<body>
    <t:saveState value="#{demoBean.name}"></t:saveState>
    <h:form id="demoForm">
        <t:outputLabel value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold"></t:outputLabel>
        <t:inputText value="#{demoBean.name}" id="txt"></t:inputText>
        <t:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{demoBean.submitButton}"></t:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

NextPage.xhtml is here

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="I am here #{demoBean.name}"></h:outputLabel>
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be useful

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but don't you just have to add

```
    <t:saveState value="#{demoBean.name}"></t:saveState>
```

to the Nextpage.xhtml per http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/SaveState ?